# cpu usage and power consumption of servers

Tags: data-request, data.gov, government, uses-of-open-data, time-series

I would like to have a structured dataset about CPU usage and power consumption of servers. The data should include CPU usage, power consumption.

Answer (score 1):

**Related**

[Numenta Anomaly Benchmark (NAB)](https://www.kaggle.com/boltzmannbrain/nab)
Dataset and scoring for detecting anomalies in streaming data

It is comprised of over 50 labeled real-world and artificial time-series data files plus a novel scoring mechanism designed for real-time applications. All of the data and code is fully open-source, with extensive documentation, and a scoreboard of anomaly detection algorithms: github.com/numenta/NAB.